# Weather Observation Station 18 HackerRank

Tags: sql-server

How should I write query for this? Consider P1(a, b) and P2(c, d) to be two points on a 2D plane.

a happens to equal the minimum value in Northern Latitude (LAT_N in STATION)
b happens to equal the maximum value in Northern Latitude (LAT_N in STATION)
c happens to equal the minimum value in Western Longitude (LONG_W in STATION)
d happens to equal the maximum value in Western Longitude (LONG_W in STATION)

Query the Manhattan Distance/Eculids Distance between points P1 and P2 and round it to a scale of 4 decimal places.

```
Table STATION(ID number, CITY varchar2(21), STATE varchar2(2), LAT_N number, LONG_W number)
```

any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way of doing this problem is
Using mathematics function [ Dis. = sqrt((x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2) ], try:
for sql server:
for Manhattan Distance:

```
select format(abs(min(LAT_N)-max(LAT_N))+abs(min(long_w)-max(long_w)),'.####') from station;
```

And for Eculids Distance:

```
select format(sqrt(square(min(LAT_N)-max(LAT_N))+square(min(long_w)-max(long_w))),'.####') from station;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CAST(ABS(MAX(LAT_N)  - MIN(LAT_N))
        + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W))as numeric(32,4))
FROM 
    STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Manhattan Distance: The distance between two points measured along axes at right angles. In a plane with p1 at (x1, y1) and p2 at (x2, y2), it is |x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
ROUND(ABS(MAX(LAT_N)  - MIN(LAT_N))
    + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)), 4) FROM STATION;
```